# Can the size of an N-dimensional array change in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

An array in Java is an object. So if I have a 2D array `double[][] matrix = new double[5][5]` then each row of that array is an object referencing a single dimensional array in memory. From my understanding, once the array size is set in java it can not be changed. So let me declare a 1D array `double[] d = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}` I am then allowed to set `matrix[1] = d` so that row 1 is now pointing to d in memory. I seems like the array size is not really fixed. I can declare `matrix` to be of any size and just change the reference to point to an array of a different size. Why am I allowed to do this if the `matrix` size is fixed to be 5 x 5 ?

Comment: this is a bit misleading.  "matrix" is a reference to an array (which is true for ANY variable...it's a reference to a thing, not the thing itself) - you can always System.arrayCopy and assign the result to matrix (even though the original array matrix pointed to is fixed in size)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assignment

```
double[][] matrix = new double[5][5];
```

actually creates 6 array objects. One array whose element type is `double[]` (i.e. an array of double arrays) having a length of 5 and referenced by the `matrix` variable, and 5 arrays whose element types are `double` having a length of 5 and references by `matrix[0]...matrix[4]`.

Just as you can change the `matrix` variable to refer to a new array by assigning :

```
matrix = new double[10][10];
```

you can also change any of the references `matrix[i]` to refer to a new array by assigning :

```
matrix[i] = new double[6];
```

You are not changing any existing array. You are changing the value of a reference variable which referred to one array to refer to a different array.

Answer (score 3):

Simply spoken: because that is how the fathers of Java made arrays work.

And the syntax gives a hint there:

```
double[][] matrix = new double[5][5]
```

You see, the 5,5 only shows up **on the right hand side**! Meaning: the array dimensions are **not** part of "type" of *matrix*!

The key thing is: there are no true "multi dimensional" arrays in Java. There is no way to say: this thing should be "5 x 5". You always end up with an array of "rows"; and each row contains an array of columns. And therefore, those columns can have **different** lengths,as they are completely independent of each other!